# react native typescript 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never.' in useNavigation

Tags: typescript, react-native, debugging, react-navigation

[I keep getting the error that says 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never' in react native typescript and I don't know why. Can someone help me fix this bug.

Thank you in advance.

[image: code picture]

code snippet :

```
const loadReport = (id: string) => {
    setPostId(id);
    navigation.navigate('Report', {postId: id});
}
```

I get an underline under 'Report'.

Comment: pls share reproducable example in ts playgroudn

Comment: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/#annotating-usenavigation

Answer (score 53, accepted):

The only solution I found is to apply the type never on the string name.

```
const goToContent = () => {
    navigate("Content" as never, {} as never);
};
```

I'm not sure it's the best solution but it's work.

Comment: The OP doesn't specify which version of react-navigation they're using but some of the other solutions are more appropriate than this one, for react navigation 6 at least.

Comment: Good for using once or twice, will create more problematic when to use at multiple places,

Answer (score 100):

This is a weird issue that happens in RN > 0.65.
My solution:

1.- Import:

```
{/* Depends of your Package (Stack or NativeStack...) */}
import { StackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/core';
```

2.- Define types

```
export type RootStackParamList = {
  YourScreen: { id: number } | undefined;
};
```

3.- Assign useNavigation hook with type StackNavigationProp.

```
const navigation = useNavigation<StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList>>();
```

4.- Use it! (Eye: with this type you can access to navigation object)

```
<TouchableOpacity
   // Use this when you pass a parameter (is optional)
   onPress={() => navigation.navigate('YourScreen', {id: 5})}>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

5.- Remember this notes:

- Specifying undefined means that the route doesn't have params. A union type with undefined => **AnyType | undefined** means that params are optional.
- The useNavigation const have special type  and this final type takes 3 generics:
- The param list object => **RootStackParamList**
- The name of the screen route => **RouteName**
- The ID of the navigator (optional) => **NavigatorID**

Obtained from: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/#annotating-usenavigation

Comment: And if I need 'YourScreen' is:
```export const SCREEN_NAME = {
YourScreen: 'YourScreen'
}
```
so there is one warning here:


```onPress={() => navigation.navigate(SCREEN_NAME.YourScreen, {id: 'smth'})}>```

Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'keyof StackParamList'.

Comment: I've got an error: `Module '"@react-navigation/native-stack"' has no exported member 'StackNavigationProp'`

Comment: @user3595795 I've got same problem

Comment: for v6, I had to update the import to work it:
`import { NativeStackNavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';`

Comment: Hi world! Thousand apologies for the delay... I'm back with React Native (specially with navigation and the error that you've commented here) => The solution is super easy. SOLUTION: Change YourScreen: {param: type} ({id: string}) for Home: { id: number } | undefined => NOTE: undefined means that the route doesn't have params. FINALLY: Check the code update ;)

Comment: If using native stack v6 use `import { NavigationProp } from '@react-navigation/native'`

Answer (score 22):

Simple solution is to add any to NativeStackNavigationProp type

```
const AppLink = ({
  text,
  screenName,
}: Link) => {

  // pass any to overload 
  const navigation = useNavigation<NativeStackNavigationProp<any>>();

  const handleNavigation = () => {
    navigation.navigate(screenName);
  };  
  
  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={handleNavigation}>
      <Text>{text}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
};

export default AppLink;
```

Comment: removing type safety is not a solution

Comment: I know, but if you need the type, you can create a type and replace it for any

Comment: I used `useNavigation<NativeStackNavigationProp<ParamListBase>>()` for a little extra type safety

Answer (score 12):

I too was getting the following ts error when not annotating `useNavigation` and trying to call `navigation.navigate('OtherJazzyScreen`)`:

```
Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ key: string; params?: undefined; merge?: boolean | undefined; } | { name: never; key?: string | undefined; params: never; merge?: boolean | undefined; }'
```

The OP doesn't specify which version of react-navigation they're using but you can fix this globally in React Navigation 6 which means you then don't have to annotate `useNavigation` directly but you still get autocomplete and type checking.

Taken from the react-navigation blog in August 2021 (https://reactnavigation.org/blog/2021/08/14/react-navigation-6.0/#better-type-safety):

> In React Navigation 6, you don’t need to annotate `useNavigation` to
> get autocompletion and type checking. This is possible by defining a
> type for the screens globally using declaration merging:
>
> ```
> declare global {   
>   namespace ReactNavigation {
>     interface RootParamList {
>       Home: undefined;
>       Profile: { userId: string };
>       NotFound: undefined;
>     }   
>   } 
>  }
> ```
>
> You can read [more about it in our TypeScript
> docs](/docs/typescript#specifying-default-types-for-usenavigation-link-ref-etc).

Another example from the React Navigation 6 docs, if you already have your params declared elsewhere:

```
// E.g. RootStackParamList.ts
export type RootStackParamList = {
  Home: undefined;
  Profile: { userId: string };
  NotFound: undefined;
};

// E.g. App.tsx
import { RootStackParamList } from 'path/to/RootStackParamList';
declare global {
  namespace ReactNavigation {
    interface RootParamList extends RootStackParamList {}
  }
}
```

Comment: This is the way. Thank you.

Answer (score 11):

Just use type `any` when calling the hook:

```js
const navigation = useNavigation<any>();
```

This isn't the recommended way of doing things but it will make the code error go away.

Comment: This saved me from the error `Argument of type '[string, { screen: string; }]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.` which occurs when you try to navigate to a *nested* screen, and there is no way to make that particular error go away, because the parameter type is `...args: never`. You cannot just put `as never` for each arg, or for both args.

Comment: This is the easiest way to ignore it. thanks for the solution.

Answer (score 3):

You could make a maintainable navigation prop.

1. Make a type file.

```js
// navigation.ts
import { DrawerNavigationProp } from "@react-navigation/drawer";
import { NavigationProp } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { StackNavigationProp } from "@react-navigation/stack";

type RootStackParamList = {
  // Your custom param type belongs here.
  Login: {
    id: string;
  },
  Profile: {}, 
}

type RootDrawerParamList = {
  Shopping: {},
  Chat: {},
}

export type RootNavigationProp = NavigationProp<
 StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList>,
 DrawerNavigationProp<RootDrawerParamList>
>;
```

2. Use it.

```js
import { useNavigation } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { RootNavigationProp } from "@somewhere/navigation";

const App = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation<RootNavigationProp>();

  function onPress () {
    navigation.navigate("Login", {id: "userID"});
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this problem as well; in my case I was starting from the Ignite boilerplate. I solved it by using:

```
const navigation = useNavigation<NativeStackNavigationProp<AppStackParamList>>()
```

Where, in my case, `AppStackParamList` is defined in `app/navigators/AppNavigator.tsx`. There can be more than one Navigator and more than one `...StackParamList`; you'll wanna use the proper param list for the navigator your component is in. By passing the param list (instead of `any`) to `NativeStackNavigationProp` the type system can infer the list of route names for suggesting in `navigation.navigate()` as well as other things relevant to your actual screen list.

Answer (score 1):

I found this solution:

```
const route = ["path", { data }];
navigation?.navigate(...(route as never));
```

Comment: I did ```navigation.navigate(...('SecondScreen' as never))``` and it works

Answer (score 1):

this is the correct solution of the typing you are searching for.

```html
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View, Button} from 'react-native';
import {StackNavigationProp} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {ParamListBase, useNavigation} from '@react-navigation/native';

enum Url {
  Page1Screen = 'Page1Screen',
  Page2Screen = 'Page2Screen',
  Page3Screen = 'Page3Screen',
}

export const Page2Screen = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation<StackNavigationProp<ParamListBase, Url>>();
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>page2</Text>
      <Button
        title="go to page 1"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Page1Screen')}
      />
      <Button
        title="go to page 3"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate('Page3Screen')}
      />
    </View>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Both solutions below work for me

```
const navigation = useNavigation<StackNavigationProp<any>>();
or
const navigation = useNavigation<any>();
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe would be underrated but my solution was simpler, I notified my team about the issue and:

```js
// @ts-ignore
navigation.navigate('WHERE_TF_I_WANT');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import { NavigationContext } from "@react-navigation/native";


const MyComponent = () => {
  const navigation = React.useContext(NavigationContext);
  
  ...
}
```

Try this

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).