# Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never' Typescript error using enum

Tags: typescript, string, react-native, object, enums

I have a file, where I am using enum to hold all my routes strings

```
enum LoggedInRoutes {
  OAK_URL = 'OakUrl',
  PROFILE = 'Profile',
  ROOT = 'Root',
}

enum TestingRoutes {
  DATA_MANAGEMENT = 'DataManagement',
}

const Routes: { [key: string]: string } = {
  ...LoggedInRoutes,
  ...TestingRoutes,
};

export default Routes;

export type RoutesType = LoggedInRoutes | TestingRoutes;
```

I then import the Routes and use them like so:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import {Button} from 'react-native'
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import Routes from './Routes';

const App = () => {
  const { navigate } = useNavigation();

  return (
    <Button
      title={'Go to url'}
      onPress={() => navigate(Routes.OAK_URL)}
    />
  );
};
export default App;
```

Typescript however throws an error

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'never'

Can anyone help? Don't know what I'm doing wrong

[image: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type never]

Comment: is `navigate` a custom function of yours? can you add it?

Comment: please provide reproducible example

Comment: Just FWIW, those types on `Routes` and `RoutesType` seem odd. I'd probably look for [this](https://tsplay.dev/WoAq8N) instead.

Comment: @Apostolos it's a function that comes from react-navigation - useNavigation()

Comment: Please read [docs](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/) for using with hook with typescript. You need to create extra types

Comment: @Apostolos your question made me dig deeper into the useNavigation and I found the answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68667766/react-native-typescript-string-is-not-assignable-to-parameter-of-type-never

and captain-yossarianfromUkraine comment then pointed me to a docs about it as well, thanks both

Comment: @verunar Can you post your Stack declaration code?